# 500 server error caused by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm writing an htaccess for handeling my links for seo friendly links. But now suddenly it says an 500 Internal Server Error?? Is there a limit on lines for htaccess?

.htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/404.html

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^choose/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ choose.php?gebruikersnaam=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

blabla, some stuff you don't need to see anymore.
```

Comment: Oke thanks! Forgotten an ( in one line!

Comment: Glad you figured that out, want me to post that as an answer for u to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few ways to debug why your `.htaccess` is not working, the fastest one is if you have access to the web server config file so you can turn on `RewriteLog` which will pinpoint where it fails for you:

```
RewriteLog "/path_to_save_it/rewrite_log" 
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Another way would be by placing your rules inside `IfModule` directive:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# your rule comes here
</IfModule>
```

For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /404/404.html

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/?$ show.php?photo=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^report/([0-9]+)/?$ report.php?photo=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^album/?$ album.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^choose/?$ choose.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^choose/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ choose.php?gebruikersnaam=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^rules/?$ rules.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^winners/?$ winners.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^forget-password/?$ password.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^forget-password/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ password.php?gebruiker=$1&wachtwoord=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^upload-picture/?$ upload.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^user-cp/?$ user-photo.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^user-cp/delete/([0-9]+)/?$ user-photo.php?delete=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^user-cp/yes/([0-9]+)/?$ user-photo.php?yes=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^mail-second/?$ mail_second.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^activate/?$ activate.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ activate.php?code=$1&gebruikersnaam=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

If all your rules have no issue but mod_rewrite is not enabled you will get no errors so you will know mod_rewrite is not enable if you try any rules.

If you still get error then it means mod_rewrite is enable and 1 or more rules are right, like missing something perhaps.

However from the above you will only know you have a problem, by using the elimination method you will find the exact line or lines that are causing the issue, which is by commenting all lines and then uncomment one by one, testing what that line is supposed to do before moving to the next line.

This way you will pinpoint where the problem is.